# Geometry Generator - Straight lines not curved

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, geometry-generator

I have QGIS 3.8.2 installed and started to look at the Geometry Generator.  I have a layer of airline tracks and trying to create a curved line linking start and end points.

I did a lot of searching and found the followng code but when I apply this I get straight lines not curved lines like I have seen elsewhere.

```
make_line(
    start_point($geometry),
    centroid(
        offset_curve(
            $geometry, 
            length($geometry)/-5.0
        )
    ),
    end_point($geometry)
)
```

Hopefully its something simple that I am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To visualize them as curved lines,  change the `Symbol layer type` to **Arrow**, then select **Curved arrows** option.

Head length/thickness should be zero as you would not need arrow-heads.

[image]